# Compile error when using QUERY like in documentaion described

Tags: c++, oat++

I'm following the documentation and got an error during compilation following example:
https://oatpp.io/docs/components/api-controller/#query-parameters-mapping
Visual Studio 2017 is complaining about C2839:invalid return type 'type' for overloaded 'operator ->' and C2232 '->' : left operand has 'class-key' type, use '.' when I try to use **age** like mentioned in the example.

```
ENDPOINT("GET", "/users", getUsers,
QUERY(Int32, age)) 
{
  OATPP_LOGD("Test", "age=%d", age->getValue());
  return createResponse(Status::CODE_200, "OK");
}
```

What's wrong with the usage/example?

Comment: What's the type of `age`? You should post a small, self contained code sample.

Comment: Like in the example. The Oat++ gives some object generated by macros as parameter to the function.

Comment: Well, I first had to dig through the code. It seems like `Int32` is some class, a wrapper type. Either way, I assume it was you who created this issue here? 
https://github.com/oatpp/oatpp/issues/556

Comment: Yes....looks like an issue with documentation. Thanks so far :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation is outdated, solution is:

```
OATPP_LOGD("Test", "age=%d", *age);
```